# Time complexity of a triple nested for loop

Tags: for-loop, time-complexity, big-o

I'm working on finding the exact & big-Oh time complexity of the following triple nested for loop and am confused if I am doing it properly.

```
for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
   for (int j=i; j<=n; j++)
      for (int k=i; k<j; k++)
          sum++;
```

I know the outer loop runs n times. Then the second loop runs a different amount of times each time since it starts at i:

n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 2 + 1.

But, since we only care about worst case scenario (which would be when i=n) then the second loop would run n-n times, since it would start at i=n. This, of course, doesn't make sense but this is where I get stuck. I've ran the code for this and found the first four elements of the sequence: S = 0 + 1 + 4 + 10 + ... + (not sure about the rest of this).

Sorry if that doesn't make sense but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to know that all arithmetic series like `1+2+3+...+n` are in `O(n^2)`. Therefore you get three nested loops that are each in `O(n)`, so the total time complexity is `O(n^3)` or, to be more precise, `Θ(n^3)`.

Note that there is no "worst-case" or "best-case" here since the number of steps is only dependent on `n` and nothing else. Compare that to e.g. sorting algorithms where the number of steps may not only depend on the number `n` of elements to be sorted, but also on the values of the elements and their particular order.

Comment: Okay that makes a lot more sense. I think I was just overthinking it to be honest. I knew it was O(n^3) but kept getting confused on the steps to get to that answer and find the "exact" time complexity. Negating everything but how many times sum++ is run, that should just be n^3 as well. Then trying to find the summation was also tripping me up. This makes sense though thank you!